# How to map an XML string as an input parameter to a stored procedure via MyBatis?

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, mybatis

I've been working on sending an XML string as an input parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure, which is called through a MyBatis mapping interface in Java. My mapping is defined like so:

```
@Update(value = "{ call prcFoo(" +
                "#{ stringValue, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN }," +
                "#{ xmlValue, jdbcType=CLOB, mode=IN } ) }") 
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
Integer sendXML(@Param("stringValue") String stringValue, 
                   @Param("xmlValue") String xmlValue);
```

The mapping returns an integer value, rather than a result set. I'm getting the procedure error condition (a negative integer) when I make a call using this mapping. It appears to be a problem with reading in the XML, because when I call the procedure directly on the database with the same XML string, it returns the expected value. Am I using MyBatis incorrectly, or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the XML data type instead of a string

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189887(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189887%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)